# Renderscript error

Tags: android, live-wallpaper, renderscript

I'm extracting Android Grass live wallpaper code from the Android source.

I have put it in an Android project.

When I run it and go to wallpaper chooser in order to pick it, I get this error that probably is related to **OpenGL** and **RenderScript**, but I can't realize what is the problem exactly.

```
E/rs(647): create2d android.renderscript.Allocation@1ead28
E/RenderScript(647): 0x1b2b78, GL Error = 0x00000500, from: Upload2DTexture 1 
E/libEGL(647): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
E/libEGL(647): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
E/libEGL(647): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
E/libEGL(647): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
W/dalvikvm(647): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
E/AndroidRuntime(647): FATAL EXCEPTION: RSMessageThread
E/AndroidRuntime(647): android.renderscript.RSRuntimeException: Fatal error 4098, details: Error linking GL Programs
E/AndroidRuntime(647):  at android.renderscript.RenderScript$MessageThread.run(RenderScript.java:829)
E/libEGL(647): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
E/libEGL(647): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
E/RenderScript(647): Attempting to bind 1 textures on shader id 1749320, but only 0 are available
E/libEGL(647): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
E/libEGL(647): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: sorry for my wackiness, and thanks to Jave for editing.

Comment: I believe qinyu's answer should probably be marked as the accepted answer at this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update to newest Android SDK(r18) and system images(4.0.3 r2), and it supports OpenGL ES 2.

Start emulator from command line with option "-gpu on".

I have run Balls Renderscripts example successfullly.

Answer (score 2):

I believe Renderscript requires opengl es 2, which your device does not seem to support. This is unfortunately the case for the Android emulator as well.

Answer (score 0):

Go to emulator editing in Avd manager. GPU emulation should be set to yes.
[image]